# Scanning a ton of pictures

Tags: photos.app, scanning

I'm rather disappointed that iPhoto has no direct ability to import from a scanner. I'm reduced to scanning in Preview, which has a less awful UI for scanning than the program that came with my HP scanner, and dragging the resulting files into iPhoto.

Is there some better scheme that I've missed?

Comment: Just a little bit better: put all your scans in a single folder and drag the folder itself into iPhoto.

Answer (score -1):

Send the photos to a scanning service, especially if you have "tons".